# How to get the html of the ElementFinder in the debugger, not a promise?

Tags: debugging, typescript, protractor

I have an element: `this.page.taskAssignment` of type `ElementFinder`. In my UI tests I click this element, but nothing happens. I suspect I click wrong element, that's why I want to check what is clicked and in order to do it I need to see html in debugger.

I wrote in WebStorm debugger: `this.page.taskAssignment.element.getTagName().then(e => {console.log(e)})` but still the result is a promise and I can't find any html.

**Question:** How do I get html of that element, not a `Promise`, but a `string`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the await keyword to get the value.

```
let formField = await element(by.formControlName(myField));
let formTag = await formField.getTagName();
let innerHtml = await browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", formField);
```

(There used to be a getOuterHtml() method but, according to the [protractor docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), selenium removed it.)

If you get an error that you can only use `await` is a reserved word it needs to be in an `async` function e.g. on your page object.

```
class myPageObject{
    async fillForm(myField) {
        let formField = await element(by.formControlName(myField));
        let formTag = await formField.getTagName();
        let innerHtml = await browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", formField);

        // .... rest of code
    }
}
```

see https://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects for more on page objects.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to identify the element that you are trying to access.

```
let elementLocator: ElementFinder;
```

**To get the tagName:**  use `await elementLocator.getTagName()` so this will return the tag name of the element.

**To get the particular Attribute of the element:** use `await elementLocator.getAttribute('class')` //if you want the class name of the locator. You can use the same to get all the locator attributes.

Note: All the above returns only as a `string`.

Hope it helps you